# Is this quotient of meromorphic functions of finite order?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $f$ and $g$ be two non-zero meromorphic functions of finite order, in the sense that two numbers $\rho_f$ and $\rho_g$ exist such that 
$$f(z)=\mathcal{O}(e^{|z|^{\rho_f}})$$
$$g(z)=\mathcal{O}(e^{|z|^{\rho_g}})$$
when $z$ goes to infinity. Suppose that the quotient
$$\frac{f}{g}$$
define an entire function (after removing removable singularities). Is $f/g$ of finite order  in the above sense ?

Thanks for your help !

(I thought using Hadamard's factorization theorem but ultimately I doubt that such a result is true)

Comment: Note that for a meromorphic function to be of finite order in this sense, it can only have finitely many poles.Take $f=1$ and $g$ to be the Riemann zeta function. Then $f/g$ has infinitely many poles, so is not of inite order in your sense.

Comment: Yes but in my case, I suppose that $f/g$ is entire which is not the case in your example. (Thanks for your answer)